# Почему значение undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

После всех элементов в html файле располагаю скрипт. В объекте **page** есть объект **obj** со значением **$(".container_main")**. В следующем объекте обращаюсь к **obj**, но браузер выдаёт ошибку.

Пример кода:

```
<script>
    var page = {
        obj: $(".container_main"), 
        height: this.obj.height(), //cannot read property 'height' of undefined
        width: this.height * 9/16
    }
</script>
```

Если не использовать объект **obj**, а напрямую обращаться к **$(".container_main")**, всё в порядке.

Пример кода, который работает:

```
<script>
    var page = {
        height: $(".container_main").height(),
        width: this.height * 9/16
    }
</script>
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Возможно проблема в прототипах внутри Jquery<br>
Используйте решение, которое вы уже сделали

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что если я поменяю версию jquery, это может помочь?

Comment: смена версии jquery не помогла

Comment: @ЕвгенийАрхипов скорее всего нет. Дело в том что скорее всего, как я подразумеваю используется прототип который вызывается от page. Т.е в данном случае вы вызываете page.height(), поэтому и пишет undefined

Comment: @ЕвгенийАрхипов нужно смотреть что внутри Jquery находится. Аспекты ООП играют тут очень важную роль (Хоть это и очевидно)

Comment: Спасибо! Я понял, что объекты, которые я заполнял  остаются пустыми до присвоения им значений через функцию, которая выполняется после загрузки body

Comment: Запусти через отладчик гугл и нажми точку остановы во время объявления переменной и просмотри чем является этот объект ибо то что написал полностью проблему не раскрывает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var page = {
    obj: $(".container_main"), 
    height: this.obj.height(), // this в этом месте это глобальный объект window, а не объект, который Вы создаете, - его еще нет
    width: this.height * 9/16
}
```

Сделайте так:

```
var page = {
    obj: $(".container_main"), 
    height: function() { return this.obj.height(); },
    width: function() { return this.height() * 9/16; }
}
console.log(page.height(), page.width());
```

Comment: Благодарю! Вы мой спаситель

Comment: @ЕвгенийАрхипов Ну что Вы! Пожалуйста. Успехов!